# Efficiently delete RedisKeys in bulk via wildcard pattern

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

**Problem**:
I need to efficiently delete keys from my Redis Cache using a wildcard pattern. I don't need atomicity; eventual consistency is acceptable.

**Tech stack**:

- .NET 6 (async all the way through)
- StackExchange.Redis 2.6.66
- Redis Server 6.2.6
- I currently have ~500k keys in Redis.
- I'm not able to use RedisJSON for various reasons

**Example**:
I store the following 3 `STRING` types with keys:

```
dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:sw:user:123
dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:fl:user:123
dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:sw:user:456
...
```

where each `STRING` stores JSON like so:

```
> dump dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:fl:user:123
"{\"Name\":\"john\",\"Age\":22}"
```

The original solution used the `KeysAsync` method to retrieve the list of keys to delete via a wildcard pattern. Since the Redis Server is 6.x, the `SCAN` feature is being used by `KeysAsync` internally by the `StackExchange.Redis` nuget.

Original implementation used a wildcard pattern `dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:*`. As one would expect, this solution didn't scale well and we started seeing `RedisTimeoutExceptions`.

I'm aware of the "avoid this in PROD if you can" and have seen Marc Gravell respond to a couple other questions/issues on SO and StackExchange.Redis GitHub. The only potential alternative I could think of is to use a Redis `SET` to "track" each `RedisKey` and then retrieve the list of values from the `SET` (which are the keys I need to remove). Then delete the `SET` as well as the returned keys.

**Potential Solution?**:

1. Create a Redis `SET` with a key of `dailynote:getitemsforuser` with a value which is the key of the form `dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:XX...`

The `SET` would look like:

```
dailynote:getitemsforuser (KEY)
    dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:sw:user:123 (VALUE)
    dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:fl:user:123 (VALUE)
    dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:sw:user:456 (VALUE)
    ...
```

I would still have each individual `STRING` type as well:

```
dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:sw:user:123
dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:fl:user:123
dailynote:getitemsforuser:region:sw:user:456
...
```

2. when it is time to do the "wildcard" remove, I get the members of the `dailynote:getitemsforuser` `SET`, then call `RemoveAsync` passing the members of the set as the `RedisKey[]`. Then call `RemoveAsync` with the key of the `SET` (`dailynote:getitemsforuser`)

I'm looking for feedback on how viable of a solution this is, alternative ideas, gotchas, and suggestions for improvement. TIA

***UPDATE***
Added my solution I went with below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the solution I suggested above where I use a Redis `SET` with a known/fixed key to "track" each of the necessary keys.

When a key that needs to be tracked is added, I call `StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.SetAddAsync (SADD)` while calling `StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.HashSetAsync (HSET)` for adding the "tracked" key (along with its TTL).

When it is time to remove the "tracked" key, I first call `StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.SetScanAsync (SSCAN)` (with a page size of 250) iterating on the `IAsyncEnumerable` and call `StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.KeyDeleteAsync (HDEL)` on chunks of the members of the `SET`.  I then call `StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.KeyDeleteAsync` on the actual key of the `SET` itself.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem with both KEYS and SCAN with Redis is that they require a complete scan of the massive hash table that stores every Redis key. Even if you use a pattern, it still needs to *check* each entry in that hash table to see if it matches.

Assuming you are calling SADD when you are also setting the value in your key—and thus avoiding the call to SCAN—this should work. It *is* worth noting that calls to SMEMBERS to get all the members of a Set can also cause issues if the Set is big. Redis—being single-threaded—will block while all the members are returned. You can mitigate this by using SSCAN instead. StackExchange.Redis might do this already. I'm not sure.

You might also be able to write a Lua script that reads the Set and UNLINKs all the keys atomically. This would reduce network but could tie Redis up if this takes too long.

Comment: Is there a way to "link" the member of the SET to the original key (like a foreign key) so that when the original key expires, it is also removed from the SET as well?

Comment: Nope. That said, calling DEL or UNLINK on a missing key doesn't cause an error. It does consume resources, of course. But since this is a direct lookup into the hash table that is Redis, this should be O(1).